# Add white spaces to image Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

is there a way to add white spaces to an image in javascript ?

I this the image 1 and I want to edit or create a new image, to add white spaces and the result would be the image 2.[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the canvas object.. if you have the image for instance

```html
    <img src="some.jpeg" id="myImg">
```

You can copy it to a new canvas and play with the drawImage properties

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width; // add here the extra width you want
canvas.height = img.height; // add here the extra height you want
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height); // play here with the position, 0, 0 are the top x,y axis
```

Here is the link to mozilla documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Answer (score 0):

The following code achieves this task. Basically, we create a canvas and set it to the size of the desired output. We then fill it with white before drawing the original image at (0,250) This centers the image (I should have done this with code, but instead looked at your output image in an image editor. (OutputHeight-InputHeight)/2 = Y offset to draw image at.

Since you're not actually adding any detail, it's possible this isn't the best way to go about what you're trying to achieve. It's possible that you should use margin/padding to expand the room the image appears to occupy.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
  let img = document.querySelector('img');
  let canvas = document.querySelector('#output');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,759,759);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 250);
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN5hp.jpg'/>
<hr>
<canvas id='output' width=760 height=760/></canvas>
```